# (Fluent) NHibernate : One entity composed of fields from different tables

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there a way of writing an NHibernate mapping so that you can have an entity that is composed of fields from different DB tables?

For Example is I have a Person and Address table, I want address fields to appear in my person object.

I want an entity like this:

```
public class person
{
    public virtual Guid Key{get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual string Age {get; set;}
    public virtual string Address1 {get; set;} //from address table
    public virtual string Address2 {get; set;} //from address table

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Fluent NHibernate you can use WithTable, as in this example:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Key, "[Key]"); // Explicitly specify escaped column name to 
                             // avoid problems with reserved words
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.Age);

    WithTable("Address", m =>
    {
      m.Map(x => x.Address1);
      m.Map(x => x.Address2);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case how does it know what that foreign key is? Will this support reading aswell and writing?

Comment: I guess it just tries to find a foreign key relationship between the tables and uses that one. I wrote a little sample app using the mapping above and a person class corresponding to the one in your question. Both reading and writing worked fine.

Comment: Seems WithTable no longer exists in Fluent 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

I think [here's](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-join) what you need. Not sure about support on Fluent NHibernate part, as well as I'm not sure about the validity of this idea.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of un-normalising my objects? Is this not one of the aims of Nhibernate? to separate my domain model from my database model?

Comment: I'm only against "Address1", "Address2", etc. Though I do understand that this is the only choice in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a many-to-many table between Person and Address.  In that case, it might make sense to have a property "Addresses" that can just hold a list of however many addresses you want.

You can do a  mapping (or whatever collection mapping works best) with a  mapping to accomplish this.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the "Fluent" part of your title...  Sorry about that.